# function that adds <SPAN>

Tags: javascript, jquery

Good morning, I have a doubt.
I have a function that adds a  click the User, the side of my input

Plus this gives an error. I wanted just once even if adicionace a person clicks the button several times the action. Do you have a scan after input  if not add another

My code.

```
//th = Name of the input that will add, at the low <SPAN>

      if(d.length == 0){
          $(th).after('<SPAN class="erro">'+txt+'</SPAN>');
          this.focus();
          return false;
      }
```

I would be very grateful for the help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should search for `span.error` first with [`$.find`](http://api.jquery.com/find), and add it only if it isn't there already:

```
  if(d.length == 0){
      var errorSpan = $(th).find("span.error").length;
      if(!errorSpan) {
          $(th).after('<SPAN class="erro">'+txt+'</SPAN>');
          this.focus();
      }
      return false;
  }
```

Comment: thanks, And so I would, More tried did not work here.

Did  var errorSpan = $ (th). find ("span.error). length;   and
        var errorSpan = $ (th). prev ("span.error). length;

Where "errorSpan" value = 0

Comment: @user628298: `"span.error"`, not `"span.error` -- is that a typo?

Comment: thanks now it worked, I put a parents
$(th).parents(".diinput").find("span.erro").length;

Answer (score 0):

use **[jQuery One](http://api.jquery.com/one/)**. Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed at most once per element.

```
$('#yourbuttonid').one('click', function() {
  if(d.length == 0){
      $(th).after('<SPAN class="erro">'+txt+'</SPAN>');
      this.focus();
      return false;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Register the event using `$('selector').one('click', function(e) { /* your code */ });` to make it fire only once.

If `th` is the input name (a string), your selector should be like `$('input[name='+th+']')` instead of `$(th)`